# Create flash-friendly file system on microSD card (not FAT32)

Tags: external-sd, file-system

Yesterday I noticed that I destroyed my just a couple of months old 32GB large microSD card. I wasn't even able to create a new file system on it or change the partition table, so it became completely unusable.

To prevent this from happening again, I want to use a different, *more flash-friendly filesystem* on my new microSD card. I am using an *unrooted* Nexus One with Android 2.3.3 on it. I know that it is quite possible to use different file systems with custom ROMs on rooted phones, but I want to use the official, unrooted version of Android.

So my question is:
Is it possible to use other file systems than FAT on a microSD card with unrooted Android? Which file system would you use then to save the flash memory from corrupting?

I am also interested in things you do to save your microSD card life.

Comment: Corruption cannot cause the card to be un-formattable.  You had a hardware problem, not a software problem.  Buy a card from Kingston or another manufacturer who make quality stuff.

Answer (score 4):

MicroSD cards already have wear leveling at the hardware level - placing software wear leveling on top of that won't help much. Just get a higher quality microSD next time.